# Confirm that the path exists

Tags: build, import, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Trying to deploy an Orchard 1.6.1 cms project to run from IIS.
When building the project (step 3 of the below link)

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop

I get 65 errors...All something along the lines of:

```
confirm that the path in the <import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
```

Any takers as to how to resolve this?

Comment: I'd bet that you didn't follow steps 1 and 2, especially 2. There's not enough information in the question to be able to tell for sure.

Comment: wasnt running command prompt as an admin....